# How to check title is being entered in Title Case?

Tags: block-editor, title

I would like to ensure that my titles are entered in Title Case. I would prefer to do this from the editor, before it is saved to the database, rather than altering what is displayed, or modifying existing titles.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for checking title case in a string? In order too connect it up you'll need one otherwise there's no point asking how to hook into the title validation if you don't know how to check if a piece of text is title case or not. Doing that part is going to be generic PHP/JS that you should ask about on Stack Overflow

Comment: I’ve got a few ideas for the checking algorithm, either PHP, or using an API to a separate service if needed.